# Why does the metal mesh in an electric swatter make a whirring sound?

Tags: electricity, acoustics, electronics

I have an electric bug swatter that operates on a rechargeable lead acid battery. I had one before that operated on disposable batteries and when it was turned on, it made a high pitched whining noise. I knew this was some sort of oscillator in this case. However, in the new swatter there is no high pitched whining coming from the handle where the electrical components are located. Instead, a whirring noise (like white noise) seems to be coming from the metal mesh itself when turned on. The sound lasts for a couple minutes before completely dying down.

What is the cause of this sound?

Comment: The switching power supply, which converts the low voltage battery to the high voltage for zapping, likely operates in the kHz range. So, you are getting some of the rapidly varying high voltage as it charges up being transferred in to mechanical noise.